# UIScrollView over MKMapView

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, uistoryboard, gestures

I'm trying to create a specific layout in an iOS App, where the "background" is a `MKMapView` and the overlay is a `UIScrollView`. The idea is that there are *two* screens, one with a map, and another with some additional information on. The user can scroll down to see this general information, and this view covers up the map and has a blurred background to create some depth.

Here's an image showing the layout:

[image: Layout image]

As you can see, the map is fixed in its position. It will always be behind the content, even if you scroll. I want the map to respond to gestures, but only when used directly on the map. When the user "scrolls" over the bottom bar, I want the content to scroll up, revealing the second page which then covers the map.

I'm lost at what to do to achieve this. I tried putting the map on the original `UIView` and then covering it up with a scrollview, but this causes the map not to respond to gestures. I only want the `UIScrollView` to respond to gestures when it's on either the bottom bar, or the second page (each is its own separate view). Otherwise I want the Map to respond to the gestures.

I hope I managed to explain it well, if not, please do not hesitate to ask questions. I appreciate all help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are adding a full screen UIScrollView on top of a MKMapView and the scrollview is picking up all the touches.

What you are asking about is not necessarily standard so there are multiple ways to implement it and you have to decide what works best for your use case.

Here is what I would do:

1. Use constraints on the scrollview to ensure that it is only covering the bottom bar area.
2. Make sure you can toggle the constant of the constraint controlling the scroll view's height  (hook up an IBOutlet if you're using storyboard).
3. Add both a swipe gesture recognizer and a tap gesture recognizer that will fire toggleScrollViewFullScreen if recognized. Ensure that these recognizers can only be recognized while the scrollView is the bottom bar.
4. Have an X-out button display in the top corner while the scrollview is in full screen.  This button can call toggleScrollViewFullScreen to dismiss the view back down.

Example toggleScrollViewFullScreen method:

```
//Toggle size of scroll view
    - (void) toggleScrollViewFullScreen {
        CGFloat bottomBarHeight = 100;
        if (self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant > bottomBarHeight){
            self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = bottomBarHeight
        }else {
            self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.bounds.size.height;
        }
        //Animate constraint change:
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
            [self.view setNeedsLayout];
        }];
    }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to let the `bottom-bar` pick up the touches and then send it to the `ScrollView`, which itself doesn't pick up any touches, effectively letting the `Map` work?

Comment: On second thoughts, that's really not very important. However, how would I implement your method with `paging`? I'd like the user to scroll normally, but lock to a page once released, rather than automatically animate to the new page when swiped.

Comment: You could do some toggling of the scrollEnabled property to get that sort of effect.

Comment: I ended up just moving the views using an UIView animation instead of a scroll view. It's not completely what I want, but it works. Thanks for the inspiration!